# Cloud Natural Language API service

Tags: google-natural-language

I want to develop an application that will detect duplicate sentence or question. Can I use Cloud Natural Language API service for detecting duplicate sentence?

Answer (score 0):

Not out of the box. As in, there is no API call where you provide 2 sentences and it tells you whether they're identical or not. But if you need to basically eliminate punctuation or something similar to make your comparison robust, you can call AnalyzeSyntax on both sentences, identify the punctuation and remove them and then do the comparison locally.